# What could have caused both belts becoming loose?

Tags: prusa-i3, repair, belt

Recently both belts on my Prusa MK3S+ became loose. Quite suddenly, too. One print was okay, the next nozzle wobbled in the Y and bed in the X causing layer shifting. More precisely, each movement was shifted pretty randomly.

I checked belt tension and there was basically none. It was good a month ago, and it must've been good enough just one print before. Of course I will tension them again, but I would be glad to know what are the possible causes of belts losing tension suddenly, to check them during the maintenance.

[image: Shot of the layers]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

Long hours of printing ASA parts for my upcoming Voron Trident, in an enclosure, made printer parts softer and belts skipped on the teeth. I needed to glue and shim belt ends in place. Next time I'll need to replace these parts, and belts. Hopefully I'll have another printer by then.